# no suitable definition provided for explicit template instantiation request

Tags: c++, templates

I have a `Calculator<T>` class and a `LoggingCalculator<T>` class, which inherites from `Calculator<T>`. `Calculator<T>` has a virtual methods like `add`, `multiply` etc. In a child class `LoggingCalculator<T>` I am trying to override these methods. I have already overrided the `add` method, fine. But I cannot override `multiply`, because compiler says:

> Calculator::Calculator[int]::Calculator(void)': no suitable definition provided for explicit template instantiation request

even though, I explicitly instantiated my templates. I really do not understand, **why this error occures with overriding `multiply` method, while `add` compiles fine**.

The really weird thing is that it **does** compile, if I do not return generic value returned from base class method. But If want to return result from the base class method, it does not compile. See `LoggingCalculator.cpp` code below.

Calculator.h:

```
template <class T>
class Calculator
{
public:
    Calculator();
    ~Calculator();
    virtual T add(T a, T b);
    virtual T multiply(T a, T b);
}
template class Calculator<int>;
template class Calculator<long>;
template class Calculator<float>;
template class Calculator<double>;
```

Calculator.cpp:

```
template<class T>
Calculator<T>::Calculator() {}

template<class T>
Calculator<T>::~Calculator() {}

template<class T>
T Calculator<T>::add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template<class T>
T Calculator<T>::multiply(T a, T b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

LoggingCalculator.h:

```
template <class T>
class LoggingCalculator : public Calculator<T>
{
public:
    LoggingCalculator();
    ~LoggingCalculator();
    T add(T a, T b) override;
    T multiply(T a, T b) override;
};

template class LoggingCalculator<int>;
template class LoggingCalculator<long>;
template class LoggingCalculator<float>;
template class LoggingCalculator<double>;
```

LoggingCalculator.cpp:

```
template<class T>
LoggingCalculator<T>::LoggingCalculator() { }

template<class T>
LoggingCalculator<T>::~LoggingCalculator() {}

template<class T>
T LoggingCalculator<T>::add(T a, T b)
{
    T result = Calculator<T>::add(a, b);
    return result;
}

template<class T>
T LoggingCalculator<T>::multiply(T a, T b)
{
    T result =  Calculator<T>::multiply(a, b);
    //return a * b; // COMPILES FINE!
    return result // CAUSES ERROR
}
```

Comment: My God, I have added semicolon after `return result` and now it compiles. Seems like it was just a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to move the explicit instantiations to their respective source files. That's because definitions of what you're instantiating need to be accessible at the point of instantiation.

What you're doing now instantiates the *definition* of the class `Calculator<int>` and with it, the *declaration* of `Calculator<int>::add`, but it does not instantiate the *definition* of `Calculator<int>::add`, because the definition is not available.

And since explicit template instantation is a definition, it should normally not appear in a header file anyway — that would likely lead to multiple-definition issues down the line.

Comment: Still, why would add work fine? I'm curious, otherwise definitely liked your answer.

Comment: Maybe I will like your answer, but how do you explain this? I added semicolon after `return result` and now it compiles. It seems like it was just a syntax error...

Comment: @Darko That it's working for you by pure chance. Being in the header, the `Calculator` instantiations appear in both translation units (= preprocessed source files), but only one of them has the definitions at hand to actually instantiate them. Still, the instantiations do *not* belong in the header, semantically.

Comment: @Darko don't include cpp files.

Comment: @Angew So where is the right place to put explicit template instantiation? Or how I should specify allowed types for the template class? I am relatively new in c++ and I am not familiar with templates in c++. I put the explicit template instantiation in the header, following some answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Darko See the answer's first sentence: "You'll have to move the explicit instantiations to their respective source files." In general, each explicit instantiation should exist *exactly once* in the program, and it needs to be in a translation unit which contains all the template definitions needed by the instantiation.

Comment: @Angew My intuition says, that `Calculator<int>::add` definition will be instantiated in my code. The definitions of all <int> methods should be provided, because I specified the definitions of generic <T> methods in a Calculator.cpp and T will be replaced with int, since I instantiated the definition of the class Calculator<int> in the header. It works now, so probably I am right (?).
But there can be misconceptions in my thinking and I should definitely read a good text about templates in c++ :)

Comment: @Darko Find a [good book in our list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) :-) But the thing is that since the instatiation is in the header, it will *also* appear in preprocessed `LogicCalculator.cpp`. And that one does *not* see the definitions from `Calculator.cpp` (remember object files are independent of each other!).

Comment: @Angew Thanks, now it is clearer for me. Did you mean `LoggingCalculator.cpp` instead of `LogicCalculator.cpp`?